# Scoping of HTML element id in Vue component

Tags: vue.js, attributes, components

Is there some built-in scoping mechanism for Vue component in the sense that value of id attribute of html element inside Vue component be uniquely defined without programmer's efforts to do it?

In the following code, I create two components and hope each behaves independently to each other. So, ideally if I click on each button, each is required to print out "foo" but actually not because value of ids are duplicated.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
    <title></title>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="app">
        <my-comp></my-comp>
        <my-comp></my-comp>
    </div>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
    <script>
        Vue.component('my-comp', {
            template: `
                <div>
                    <button id="btn" @click="onClick">Click me</button>
                    <div id="pid"></div>
                </div>
            `,
            methods: {
                onClick(e) {
                    $('#pid').text("foo");
                }
            },
        });

        const vm = new Vue({
            el: '#app',
            data: () => ({}),
            methods: {}
        });
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Have you checked this package ? https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-uniq-ids

Comment: Oh thank you so much. This exactly addresses the issue of this kind. Glad to know I am not alone, who suffering the same issue.

Comment: Ok glad to help ! I post it as an answer then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use `id` in vue components unless you are passing a unique value for it using props. You should very rarely ever actually need to get a reference to an element in vue and if you do find you need to then you should be using [refs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#ref).

In your case you can just use a property and template binding to handle things for you:

```js
Vue.component('my-comp', {
    template: `
                <div>
                    <button @click="onClick">Click me</button>
                    <div>{{ text }}</div>
                </div>
            `,
    data() {
        text: ''
    },
    methods: {
        onClick(e) {
            this.text = 'foo'
        },
    },
})
```

Comment: Actually I am considering to wrap hicharts.js graph in Vue component and highcarts chart API needs DOM element or id in string. Is there a way to get DOM element for <div>{{ text }}</div> if use of id is not  recommended? Use of ref inside Vue component seems not allowed as I tried it just now.

Comment: Where else would you use ref? It's designed to be a quick reference to elements inside your component. You can use it in the mounted lifecycle hook as well as in methods. Personally I'd just go with one of the existing implementations of [Highcharts in Vue](https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-vue).

Comment: Thank you for the tips. I will take a closer look at how ref is used. I thank you so much for introducing Highcharts Vue.

Comment: ref works very well. It turns out to be a perfect replacement for id! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the [vue-uniq-ids](http://npmjs.com/package/vue-uniq-ids) package is what you're looking for.

> It is a trend to use components. Components are cool, they are small,
>   obvious, easy to use and modular. Untill it comes to the id property.
>
> Some HTML tag attributes requires using an id property, like
>   label[for], input[form] and many of aria-* attributes. And the problem
>   with the id is that it is not modular. If several id properties on the
>   page will has the same value they can affect each other.
>
> VueUniqIds helps you to get rid of this problem. It provides the set
>   of id-related directives which value is automatically modified by
>   adding unique string while keeping the attrbitue easy to read.